# How to reverse combn in R to get the unique list of column names?

Tags: r, combn

I have a large data frame which I have used combn to generate the number of unique combinations (over 100,000). Once I get the results from the correlation test ( estimate, p value) and I undertake some filtering, I remove some of the combintations. I would like to obtain from this combn generated list the column names of the dataframe that remain after filtering. For example, if I had the filtering results as follows from an original dataframe containing 5 columns named A-D.

```
     A  B
     A  C
     A  D
     A  E
     B  C
     B  D
     B  E
     C  D
     C  E
     D  E
```

if I took the colnames from the first it would miss E, and from the second it would miss A. I was wondering how could I go from these pairs of values generated from combn, to the original list of A, B, C, D, E.

Comment: Do you want `sort(unique(unlist(yourdat)))`

Comment: @akrun just to check, would the yourdat be my dataframe with only the two columns of unique combinations generated from combn?